Laravel guzzle http client not able to catch error using error handling
$endpoint = rtrim($site->url,"/").'/'.env('WP_ENDPOINT');

try {     
  $request = Http::post($endpoint);
  dd($request);            
} catch (\Guzzle\Http\Exception\ConnectException $e) {
  $response = json_encode((string)$e->getResponse()->getBody());
}

I am trying to get response from a remote URL using guzzle http client but i get error 'cURL error 6: Could not resolve host:' on line 4.
$request = Http::post($endpoint);
I used try catch to handle the error but nothing happened so far.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

The error is about the CURL URL. Check the URL may be you are passing wrong url there.

@sandipbharadva yes it is wrong but how can i handle it using try catch so that i can redirect to listing page, right now it is showing the laravel error page with error 'cURL error 6: Could not resolve host:'

try \Exception instead of \Guzzle\Http\Exception\ConnectException

you mean like this 'catch (\Exception $e)'

Yes, It will handle all other exceptions

is it working or not?

Now it is showing this error
'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Client\ConnectionException::getResponse()'

use $e->getMessage()

$response = json_encode((string)$e->getMessage());
dd($response);
It is now coming inside catch but I want to redirect if error comes 'URL error 6: Could not resolve host:'

where you want to redirect?

To the listing view

you can write the below line for that
return view('viewName');

@sandipbharadva Thanks for your answer, it really helped me solve the issue.

Please upvote the comment so it helps to others

actually i didn't work anytime with laravel guzzle but i read something about guzzle's requests and you should always catch these two types of common timeouts, connection timeouts and request timeouts can you try like this your post request:
    $retry_count = 0;
    do{
      try{
         $response = $client->post($endpoint);
      }
      catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException $e) {
        // log the error here

        Log::Warning('guzzle_connect_exception', [
            'url' => $this->request->fullUrl(),
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ]);
      } 
      catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e) {
        Log::Warning('guzzle_connection_timeout', [
            'url' => $this->request->fullUrl(),
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ]);
      }
      if(++retry_count == 5){
        break;
      }
    }while(!is_array($response));

if you find any issue on this code, please notify me!

Do not use env() outside the config file.
Laravel's Http client does not throw exceptions unlike Guzzle. Be sure to read the official documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/http-client#error-handling
// try-catch style

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\RequestException;

try {     
  $response = Http::post($endpoint)->throw();
  dd($response);            
} catch (RequestException $e) {
  //
}

// Laravel style

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
    
$response = Http::post($endpoint);

if ($response->successful()) {
  //
} else {
  //
}

